# Twilio Video for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, twilio

I need to implement a video chat functionality using Twilio in Xamarin Forms. I've tried multiple variants, but didn't get something to work. I really want to get it working in Xamarin Forms, otherwise I'll have to choose another tech.

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching with my colleagues, we found a working example for Xamarin Native, but not for Xamarin Forms. We asked through official channels and it seems they don't have support for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have this binding for Android working with Twilio v6.2.0
I've tested it and it is working in production (at least on Android).

https://github.com/guillermo-gerard/Twilio.Video.Android.Xamarin.Binding

Feel free to check it out and let me know if you have any doubt about it